# How to write multiline javascript code to file with node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I generate some jS code on the front end and i want to write it to a js file by making an api call to a node server and i'm having some trouble with 1) ensuring the code isnt written to file as a literal string and 2) ensuring that multiple lines are preserved.

Here's my code for how ive attempted this:

```
//client
var bar = "mongolia"; //this value changes hence pulling it into variable
var jsCode = "function(){ \n
baz = foo(" + bar + "); \n
   return baz*2;"
var data = {
    code: jsCode
 }
 $http.post('api/code', data).success(function(savedCode){
   console.log("successful and the saved code is", savedCode);
 }); 
//server

'use strict';

var jf = require('jsonfile'),
    util = require('util');

var codeFile = './code/js/autoGen.js';

exports.addCode = function(req, res) {
  var newCode = req.body.code;
    //write to file
  return jf.writeFile(codeFile, newCode, function(err) {
      if(!err) {
        return res.json({newCode: newCode});          
      }
      else {
        return res.send(err);
      }
    });
};
```

When i run this, I get a syntax error in my jsCode definition.

Comment: A syntax error where? Also, why are you using `jsonfile`? Can't you just use `var fs = require('fs'); fs.writeFile(//...`?

Comment: Also, you should remove all those `return`s in your `exports.addCode`

Comment: syntax error in my jsCode definition--> var jsCode = ..., also no real reason for using jsonfile i was using it in a difft project and converted it...any idea why the core function on the client isn't working though?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript syntax for multiline strings is as follows:

```
var jsCode = "function(){ \
baz = foo(" + bar + "); \
   return baz*2;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got around both issues by

1) Using coffeescript for multiline strings and the #{} interpolation pattern for including the variable portions

2) Using fs for writing to file (Thanks for the tip @verybadalloc)

Comment: You don't need coffeescript. Check out @punund's answer